# How to load active class for link in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Created one simple tab for loading components,  tabs are working fine but a "active" class loading for all Navlinks, on rendering. "active" class should load only for active tab. please help to fix this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"; 
 
function SidenavSection(props) {
const [active, setActive] = useState("tab1")

    return (
        <div>          
            <div >
            <div sm="3" className='border sideNav'>
            <NavLink to="" className="btn btn-link"    onClick={() => setActive("tab1")}>Overview</NavLink> <br/>
            <NavLink to="" className="btn btn-link"  onClick={() => setActive("tab2")}>Align & Ratio</NavLink> <br/>
            <NavLink to="" className="btn btn-link"    onClick={() => setActive("tab3")}>Avatar</NavLink> <br/>       

                </div>
                <div sm="9" className='border'>                   
                    <div>
                    {active === "tab1" && <div>section component 1</div>}
                    {active === "tab2" && <div>section component 2</div>}
                    {active === "tab3" && <div>section component 3</div>}
               
            </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default SidenavSection;
```

[image: screenshot output]

Comment: can you add screenshot of output

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE8LA.png

Comment: ok i got your problem but how are you setting the class active on navigate I can't see any method in your code.

Comment: I wanted to get the code to set  active css class to each link

Comment: The [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink) component automatically sets the `active` class if the current path matches the `to` path. In your case `to` is an empty string which is considered a match, causing the `NavLink` to be active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use NavLink for this.
You can achieve active class by adding a **ternary operator** for the classnames.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
    export default function App() {
      const [active, setActive] = useState("tab1");
    
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div sm="3" className="border sideNav">
          <p
            to=""
            className={`btn btn-link ${active === "tab1"? "active":""}`}
            onClick={() => setActive("tab1")}
          >
            Overview
          </p>{" "}
          <br />
          <p
            to=""
            className={`btn btn-link ${active === "tab2" && "active"}`}
            onClick={() => setActive("tab2")}
          >
            Align & Ratio
          </p>{" "}
          <br />
          <p
            to=""
            className={`btn btn-link ${active === "tab3" && "active"}`}
            onClick={() => setActive("tab3")}
          >
            Avatar
          </p>{" "}
          <br />
        </div>
        <div sm="9" className="border">
          <div>
            {active === "tab1" && <div>section component 1</div>}
            {active === "tab2" && <div>section component 2</div>}
            {active === "tab3" && <div>section component 3</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should however try making an object or array including the links data, so you can easily loop through without much code, and setting active link also will be easier this way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("0");
  const els = [
    {tab:1, name: "Overview",},
    {tab:2, name: "Avatar"},
    {tab:3, name: "Align & Ratio"},
  ]
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div sm="3" className="border sideNav">
          {
            els.map((item, index)=>{
              return <p 
                onClick={()=>{setActive(index)}} 
                key={index}  
                className={index === active ? "active" : ""}
              >
                {item.name}
              </p>
            })
          }
          <br />
        </div>
        <div sm="9" className="border">
          <div>
            {active === "tab1" && <div>section component 1</div>}
            {active === "tab2" && <div>section component 2</div>}
            {active === "tab3" && <div>section component 3</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am using above accepted code, need one clarification... 
{active === "tab1" && <div><OverviewLanding/></div>} , if this have a component OverviewLanding with links which need to lead tab2, 3,4 and .etc..  is it possible to control  side tab nav items & corresponding tab loading from those links from the loaded component  OverviewLanding ?

Comment: screenshot   https://ibb.co/d0Z1zLN

Comment: demo :    https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-h39zlx?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use routing/conditional displaying using Javascript, here your trying to use both.

Without routing

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom"; 
 
function SidenavSection(props) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState("tab1")

    const isActive = (key) => (active === key ? 'active' : '');

    return (
        <div>          
            <div >
            <div sm="3" className='border sideNav'>
            <a href="" className=`btn btn-link ${isActive('tab1')}`    onClick={() => setActive("tab1")}>Overview</a> <br/>
            <a href="" className=`btn btn-link ${isActive('tab2')}`  onClick={() => setActive("tab2")}>Align & Ratio</a> <br/>
            <a href="" className=`btn btn-link ${isActive('tab3')}`    onClick={() => setActive("tab3")}>Avatar</a> <br/>       

                </div>
                <div sm="9" className='border'>                   
                    <div>
                    {active === "tab1" && <div>section component 1</div>}
                    {active === "tab2" && <div>section component 2</div>}
                    {active === "tab3" && <div>section component 3</div>}
               
            </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default SidenavSection;
```